# Is this scientifically useful exoplanet transit data?

Tags: astronomy, data-analysis, data, exoplanets

For a physics project, I am trying to derive properties of exoplanets through their transit light curve. I tried to get the data myself, on the known exoplanet Qatar-6b.

My Equipment:
8" Newt. Telescope
Canon 5D Mark II (45s exposure, ISO 1600)
Everything was tracked/guided

I processed the data in AstroImageJ, and took the moving point average in google sheets (based every 20 data points) for the transiting star. The reference star has a simple linear fit.
For some reason the brightness of the stars seemed to increase over time, but I believe it was due to the star rising (less atmosphere it has to go through) and the moon setting.

[image: Qatar-6b Transit Light Curve]

Comment: define "scientifically useful" :) of course data is always good. Publishable? I doubt it. Get in touch with the variable star team of your local astronomy society and team up with them and others to measure transients with long (~day) time windows. It's hard to do that with professional telescopes (field of view) but can be done by citizen scientists (spread across continents). The company Unistellar is co-organizing some of those observing campaigns too.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't put units on the axes so it's impossible to tell.

However, if the y-axis is some sort of flux, then no, the data are far too noisy to study the transit.

If the units are magnitudes, then the data might be more reasonable - a scatter of a few thousandths of a magnitude should resolve the transit. The shape of the "transit" you show is reminiscent of the light curve presented by [Alsubai et al. (2018)](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-3881/aaa000) of this *grazing* transit.